# Why Tensorflow runs slow on Xeon board?

Tags: python, tensorflow, cpu

I am running the same simple LSTM network training code on two computers. The first one is and old PC with Intel Core i3-4130 CPU @ 3.40 GHz, the second one is Intel Xeon CPU E5-2650 @ 2.00 GHz. In both cases top shows ~200% CPU usage, but the first reports 4 CPU, whereas the second reports 32 CPU. Execution times are 2m11.993s (real), 3m54.142s (user) for i3 processor and 2m45.295s (real), 4m54.380s (user) for Xeon. I have read that Tensorflow uses all available cores by default, so I would expect faster training on Xeon Board (2 sockets, 8 cores x 2 threads each). Is it some error on my side, or there are some Tensorflow parameters or variables which should be used in such a case?

Comment: There's not enough information to answer this question. It might be due to data processing bottleneck, or to the fact that LSTM networks are generally poor at parallelism, or other things still. Two suggestions: look into tensorboard profilers; try with a CNN instead

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.